# Fix "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Event_Manager.Form3+MyClass]" in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to sort dates that are saved in a text document, i have done this using a List. When I try to save the details back into a text document, and inside the document all I see saved is

`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Event_Manager.Form3+MyClass] ``

This code below is executed with a button, that supposedly sorts the dates, but i can't even see if this code actually sorts the dates, because i keep getting

`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Event_Manager.Form3+MyClass] ``

saved instead of the original data.

I have tried using .ToString() to prevent this from happening, but it still shows the save output saved into the document.

```
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader("Events.txt");

            List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] split = line.Split(',');

                MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

                myclass.date = DateTime.Parse(split[2]);

                myClassList.Add(myclass);
            }

            file.Close();

            // Sort the list by date
            List<MyClass> myClassListSorted = myClassList.OrderByDescending(x => x.date).ToList();

            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"Events.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var item in myClassList)
                {
                    sr.WriteLine(myClassListSorted.ToString());

                }
                sr.Close();
            }
```

I should be able to see the actual data that i originally had saved in the text document, but with sorted **dates**, rather it just has `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Event_Manager.Form3+MyClass] ``

Comment: As noted in the marked duplicates, when you see the name of a type, you're seeing the default implementation of `ToString()`. When this is a list, nearly always what you _really_ wanted was to somehow represent the list's _contents_ as text, not the list object itself. See marked duplicates for various techniques for achieving that.

Comment: Peter - that was only one part of the problem. Read my comment for the second half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through the unsorted list and then trying to write the sorted list object (not the items INSIDE the sorted list). Near the end you should be doing this:

```
foreach (var item in myClassListSorted)
{
     sr.WriteLine(item.date.ToString());
}
```

Format the date property as needed. Or you can save the original line in each MyClass and then write that line out to the file after sorting.

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
            string[] split = line.Split(',');
            MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
            myclass.date = DateTime.Parse(split[2]);
            MyClass.originalLine = line; // <---------
            myClassList.Add(myclass);
}
```

And then later in the loop:

```
     sr.WriteLine(item.originalLine);
```

That way the data in the text file is the same but just now in sorted order.

Comment: Thanks soo much, I've been trying for soo long and you saved me :)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to upvote! :)